# "Use of uninitialized value $ in concatenation (.) or string..." error even when values are initialized

Tags: perl, variables, exception, initialization

I have a problem with initialized values. I have a script which has method:

```
sub compare_with_terminal {
    use Term::Size::Any qw( chars pixels );
    my $columns = 0; 
    my $rows = 0;
    ($columns, $rows) = chars *STDOUT{IO};  

    print "Columns: ".$columns."\n"; #line 73
    print "Rows: ". $rows."\n";

    if($height > $columns || $width > $rows){
        print "Bigger than terminal: ";
        my $option = <>;
        chomp($option);
        if($option eq "N"){
            print "End.";
            exit 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I created and initialized two values `$columns` and `$rows`. But, when I run this script, I get:

> Use of uninitialized value $columns in concatenation (.) or string at
>           ./perl/script.pl line 73 (#1)
>       (W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
>       defined.  It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake.
>       To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.

`$rows` has same error.

These errors say that I didn't initialize variable `$columns`, but I did. Anyone can explain me and try to solve this problem?

Comment: What's line 73? (I'm guessing you haven't shown it, because you don't use `$columns` in a string anywhere in your snippet)

Comment: I read console size and write it into `$columns` and `$rows` variables. They are numbers I hope, not a strings. On windows everything works fine and I don't get any errors.

Comment: You do not check if $columns is defined after you assign to it.

Comment: @stevesliva - so where I should check this? If I assign to it I think they should be defined?

Comment: @allocer Again, please show which line is line 73, since that's the one the warning mentioned.

Comment: I cut this line, because it is  only a simple print `print "Columns: ".$columns."\n";`

Comment: @toolic - but I've done ` my $columns = 0; 
    my $rows = 0;`

Comment: Ok so how to repair it?

Comment: Re "*These errors say that I didn't initialize variable $columns*", If you actually read the message, it doesn't say that at all. It says `$columns` has an undefined value, not that it wasn't "initialized". (In fact, it's impossible not to initialize in Perl. Scalars are automatically initialized to `undef`, and arrays and hashes are initialized empty.)

Comment: @allocer In the future, please copy and paste the exact code you're actually running or create a [mcve]. Otherwise it makes it harder for us to find your issue.

Comment: @ikegami - so it cannot get terminal size values from `chars *STDOUT{IO}`? But only in Unix.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Ok, sorry, I edited my code.

Comment: I didn't say anything of the kind. I'm not familiar with the module, and I don't have time to familiarize myself with it,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There is a bug report for Term::Size::Any](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=83456)

Using `char` without any arguments returns values for me on linux (`Term::Size::Any` version 0.002):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Term::Size::Any qw(chars);
my ($columns, $rows) = chars();
print "$columns $rows\n";

__END__

80 24
```

You initialized $column to 0, but it is overwritten when you call the `chars` function.

Comment: It looks ok. I tested it on Windows and everything works fine. Soon I'll check it on Unix.

Comment: Note: `chars()` is equivalent to `chars(*STDIN)`, so you should probably be using `chars(*STDOUT)` instead.